# Generate all possible combinations of pairs of triplets from 3 vectors together with their original coordinates

Tags: matlab, performance, permutation, combinatorics, matrix-indexing

Given 3 row vectors `A,B,C` in Matlab, I want to generate the matrix `D` reporting all the possible combinations of pairs of triplets from `A,B,C` together with their original coordinates in `A,B,C`.

I have written a code that does what I want. As I'm trying to optimise my code as much as I can (the code should be repeated millions of times), I would like to know whether you can think of more efficient solutions. For example, in my code I am not pre-allocating the matrix `D` because I don't know how to get the index of each pair of triplets and this is not efficient.

The code below will explain it better:

```
clear 
A=[1 2];
B=[-4 -2 5];
C=[8 9 -3 0];

sA=size(A,2);
sB=size(B,2);
sC=size(C,2);
sT=sA*sB*sC;

%Generate the matrix D of dimension [sT*(sT-1)/2]x[12]
%reporting all the possible combinations of pairs of triplets from A,B,C
%together with their original coordinates in A,B,C

[ca, cb, cc] = ndgrid(A, B, C);
T = [ca(:), cb(:), cc(:)];  %matrix of dimension sTx3 reporting all the possible triplets 
                            %from A,B,C

[ca, cb, cc] = ndgrid(1:sA, 1:sB, 1:sC);
Tcoord = [ca(:), cb(:), cc(:)];  %matrix of dimension sTx3 reporting the coordinates of all 
                                 %the possible triplets from A,B,C

D=[];
for w=1:sA*sB*sC
    for r=w+1:sA*sB*sC 
        D=[D; T(w,:) T(r,:) Tcoord(w,:) Tcoord(r,:)];
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last nested for loop that populates the matrix `D` can be much more efficient. The OP is spot on in their statement:

> *"For example, in my code I am not pre-allocating the matrix D because I don't know how to get the index of each pair of triplets and this is not efficient."*

We can vectorize much of the work in those loops by noticing that there is a pattern which the OP alludes to in their comments about the final size of the matrix `D` (i.e. `Generate the matrix D of dimension [sT*(sT-1)/2]x[12]`). That first dimension will look familiar to anybody that has worked with series and sequences quite a bit. It is the formula of [Triangle Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

With this in mind, we can see that in the final result, the first 3 columns (and columns 7 through 9) repeats 23 times, then 22 times, and so on while the columns 4 through 6 (and 10 through 12) are the last 23 rows of `T/Tcoord`, the last 22 rows of `T/Tcoord` and so on. In code we have:

```
D1 = zeros(sT * (sT - 1) / 2, 12);
s = 1;
e = sT - 1;

for w = 1:(sT - 1)
    D1(s:e,[1:3,7:9]) = repmat([T(w,:),Tcoord(w,:)], sT - w, 1);
    D1(s:e,[4:6,10:12]) = [T((w+1):sT,:),Tcoord((w+1):sT,:)];
    s = e + 1;
    e = e + (sT - (w + 1));
end
```

And running each method 200 times using `tic` and `toc`, we see that we have nearly a `35%` increase in efficiency.

```
% OP's setup code goes here

tic
for i=1:200
    D=[];
    for w=1:sA*sB*sC
        for r=w+1:sA*sB*sC
            D=[D; T(w,:) T(r,:) Tcoord(w,:) Tcoord(r,:)];
        end
    end
end
toc

tic
for i = 1:200
    D1 = zeros(sT * (sT - 1) / 2, 12);
    s = 1;
    e = sT - 1;

    for w = 1:(sT - 1)
        D1(s:e,[1:3,7:9]) = repmat([T(w,:),Tcoord(w,:)], sT - w, 1);
        D1(s:e,[4:6,10:12]) = [T((w+1):sT,:),Tcoord((w+1):sT,:)];
        s = e + 1;
        e = e + (sT - (w + 1));
    end
end
toc

% Gives same result
isequal(D, D1)

% Timing for 200 runs on 24 total combinations
Elapsed time is 2.09613 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.35988 seconds.
ans = 1
```

If we make the input vectors larger, we see an even greater improvement in efficiency. Below are the results of running over each method 15 times on the following vectors:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 23];
B=[-4 -2 5 74];
C=[8 9 -3 0];

% Timing for 15 run on 80 total combinations
Elapsed time is 4.00448 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.379919 seconds.
ans = 1
```

That is more than 10x time faster. The gap grows exponentially as the size of your input vectors gets larger.

```
A=[1 2 3 4 23];
B=[-4 -2 5 74 28];
C=[8 9 -3 0 -100 -5];

% Timing for 1 run on 150 total combinations
Elapsed time is 3.63065 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.0481789 seconds.
ans = 1
```

That is about 75 times faster!!!

## Update

The OP has given a far superior answer in the comments:

```
indices=nchoosek((1:1:sT),2);
D=[T(indices(:,1),:) T(indices(:,2),:) Tcoord(indices(:,1),:) Tcoord(indices(:,2),:)];
```

Here is the code I benchmarked with:

```
clear 
A=[1 2 3 4 23 24 25 26];
B=[-4 -2 5 74 28 10 11 12 13];
C=[8 9 -3 0 -100 -5 60 120];

sA=size(A,2);
sB=size(B,2);
sC=size(C,2);
sT=sA*sB*sC;

tic
for i = 1:10
    [ca, cb, cc] = ndgrid(A, B, C);
    T = [ca(:), cb(:), cc(:)];
    [ca, cb, cc] = ndgrid(1:sA, 1:sB, 1:sC);
    Tcoord = [ca(:), cb(:), cc(:)];

    D1 = zeros(sT * (sT - 1) / 2, 12);
    s = 1;
    e = sT - 1;

    for w = 1:(sT - 1)
        D1(s:e,[1:3,7:9]) = repmat([T(w,:),Tcoord(w,:)], sT - w, 1);
        D1(s:e,[4:6,10:12]) = [T((w+1):sT,:),Tcoord((w+1):sT,:)];
        s = e + 1;
        e = e + (sT - (w + 1));
    end
end
toc

tic
for i = 1:10
    indices=nchoosek((1:1:sT),2);
    D=[T(indices(:,1),:) T(indices(:,2),:) Tcoord(indices(:,1),:) Tcoord(indices(:,2),:)];
end
toc

isequal(D, D1)
```

And here are the results:

```
% Timing for 10 runs on 576 total combinations
Elapsed time is 1.9834 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.13818 seconds.
ans = 1
```

The improved solution I provided is better than the original by a good margin, but is no match for the updated solution by the OP. It is orders faster and quite elegant, I might add.

Comment: Thanks. How about `indices=nchoosek((1:1:sT),2); D=[T(indices(:,1),:) T(indices(:,2),:) Tcoord(indices(:,1),:) Tcoord(indices(:,2),:)];`?